# How to convert a localized timestamp to UTC using Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp, pytz

I need to convert a "localized" timestamp in an arbitrary timezone to a unix timestamp (in UTC).

```py
>>> import pytz

# This represents 2019-09-11T16:14:00 (US/Central) or 2019-09-11T21:14:00 UTC!
>>> local_timestamp = 1568218440 

>>> tz = pytz.timezone("US/Central")

>>> my_unix_timestamp = unix_timestamp(local_timestamp, tz)

>>> print(my_unix_timestamp)
1568236440 # 2019-09-11T21:14:00
```

I know this has been asked many times before, but I was getting hung up on the initial conversion of the timestamp from an arbitrary timezone, because you must explicitly set the `tz` when you construct your initial `datetime` object (as noted in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the [`pytz` documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic), the standard Python `datetime.replace()` method does not properly account for daylight-savings time. You should use pytz's `timezone.localize()` method.

The other gotcha is that you must explicitly define the `tz` info when creating a `datetime` object from the input timestamp. Otherwise, it is assumed that your timestamp is in local (system) time. As noted in the [`datetime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp), you should avoid `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` for this reason.

So:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def unix_timestamp(local_timestamp, local_timezone):
    """turn the input timestamp into a UTC `datetime` object, even though
    the timestamp is not in UTC time, we must do this to construct a datetime
    object with the proper date/time values"""
    dt_fake_utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(local_timestamp, tz=timezone.utc)

    """remove the (incorrect) timezone info that we supplied """
    dt_naive = dt_fake_utc.replace(tzinfo=None)

    """localize the datetime object to our `timezone`. You cannot use
    datetime.replace() here, because it does not account for daylight savings
    time"""
    dt_local = local_timezone.localize(dt_naive)

    """Convert our datetime object back to a timestamp"""
    return int(dt_local.timestamp())
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. related, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo) are the docs on the new `zoneinfo` module in Python v3.9.

Comment: so you really need to work with "wrong" timestamps... I wonder if that gives correct output e.g. during DST changes? As I understand, what you need to know is the UTC offset of the origin timezone to correct the timestamp to refer to UTC. However, at the moment of conversion, how would you know upfront what the UTC offset is as you only have the timestamp and not time & date?